# preview image as per resolution in <img>

Tags: css, html

I have `<img>` tag of height = "100%" width = "30%".
when I click on upload file , the selected image is viewed in `<img>` tag.
But the image gets stretched or squeezed as per resolution.
How to show full image in `<img>` tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resize an image while keeping the aspect ratio in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320761/how-do-i-resize-an-image-while-keeping-the-aspect-ratio-in-css)

Comment: not working. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/omkaoazg/

Comment: @GiteshKothavale change height = "100%" width = "100%"

Comment: Just mention only 1 attribute in img or through css. width or height. Rest will be done by the browser perfectly.

Comment: its stretching and squeezing the image

Answer (score 0):

Set either one or the other, not both (in terms of width or height):

```css
img{
  width:50%;
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300"/>
```

Notice how an image (usually 200*300) is now stretched to 50% of the width of the screen, and its height will adjust accordingly?

Comment: now here instead of scroll i want full image to be viewed in that rectangle div (small size as per resolution without affecting actual look of image).

Comment: then remove the css altogether. The image will be its native size.

Comment: the size of my div is half the screen . removing css gives scroll to div because of resolution. I want to resize the image to show it inside div.

Comment: has the containing div got a specific height? if so in your image you can set max-height: /*height of containing div*/

Comment: but then it stretches the image.

Comment: if this answered your question, could you possibly mark it as accepted? (by pressing the tick on the left hand side of my answer)