# Image resizing with CSS to fit into a container

Tags: css, image, image-resizing, aspect-ratio

I'm looking for a solution to resize my `<img>` element with CSS:

1. Must keep aspect ratio for landscape *and* square *and* portrait
   images
2. Must work in upscale (shrinking) and downscale (stretching) scenarios
3. In addition to Chrome/FF/Safari/Opera must also work in IE 10/Edge (IE 8+ support is nice to have)

None of the solutions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991351/css-force-image-resize-and-keep-aspect-ratio) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757782/how-to-preserve-aspect-ratio-when-scaling-image-using-one-css-dimension-in-ie6)) I found here works as required. [The best one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320761/how-do-i-resize-an-image-while-keeping-the-aspect-ratio-in-css) that uses `object-fit: contain` does not work in IE. Is it doable without javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set a max-width and max-height for your img element. 
Providing that your images are larger than the container, this trick should resize your images in the correct ratio.

I have an example here:

```
img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Himechi90/pen/MaoEWg

Good luck!

Comment: This does not work when an image has lower resolution, i.e. needs to be stretched to fill any space available.

Comment: Very true. That's why I said in my comment "Providing that your images are larger than the container.." But thanks for pointing it out!