# Image height not scaling on HTML/CSS/Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so I have 5 different images; I want all of them to have the same height and width and scale depending on the browser's screen size. The problem is, only my width scales while the height stays the same. Here's my code:

```
.image-fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image-vertical-fill {
    /* [disabled]height: 600px; */
    min-height: auto;
    max-height: 600px;
    /* [disabled]min-height: 600px; */
```

In the image-fill code, I tried setting the height to "auto" and this fixes the problem. The problem is, one of my images' height is less than 600px so there's 4 images with the same height and one image's height is smaller than the others. Putting the height on "100%" makes all of their heights the same but the image no longer scales. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you make a live test by adding code snippet here?

Comment: I'll try, I'm using Dreamweaver so right now I have 7000+ lines of code on my css. I'm not sure a snippet can run that much code haha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scale image with css to both width and height to scale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158023/scale-image-with-css-to-both-width-and-height-to-scale)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me :(

Comment: @ElijahChan height is overridden by min-height and max-height. Putting a max-height basically determines what the height will be. Why don't you set width to a % and then height to auto? Or vv.., that would normally work..